# How to tell gcc to not use inbuilt functions

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to override some standard library functions using LD_PRELOAD. However, I notice that my version is never called for some functions, for example, the `gettimeofday` one. I suspect gcc uses an inbuilt version for some of these functions.

Is there a way I can tell gcc to not use inbuilt standard library functions.

Comment: you already have got an answer for your question itself. But there is little chance that `gettimeofday` is a builtin. So most probably you are looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the gcc switch `-fno-builtin`. Quoting from the gcc manual:

> -fno-builtin
>
> Don't recognize built-in functions that do not begin with `_*builtin*' as prefix.

More details: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC7

Answer (score 3):

You are fixing the wrong problem. I think you have a problem in the code or in how you compile the preloaded library.

I have no problems whatsoever in interposing `gettimeofday()`. Consider this `libgettimeofday.c`:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz __attribute__((unused)) )
{
    tv->tv_sec = 1;
    tv->tv_usec = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

and this `gettimeofday.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
int main(void)
{
    struct timeval  t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    printf("%ld.%06d\n", (long)t.tv_sec, (int)t.tv_usec);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile using

```
gcc -W -Wall gettimeofday.c -o gettimeofday
gcc -W -Wall -fPIC libgettimeofday.c -ldl -shared -Wl,-soname,libgettimeofday.so -o libgettimeofday.so || exit $?
```

and test:

```
$ ./gettimeofday
1355243621.698927

$ LD_PRELOAD=./libgettimeofday.so ./gettimeofday
1.000002
```

Note that I tested this in both Ubuntu (64-bit) and CentOS 6.3 (32-bit), which use different C libraries.

Comment: You are right, I actually forgot to recompile my library after adding the gettimeofday function to it :)!